# WPF не работает SelectedItem DataGrid в RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть **DataGrid** и в его **RowDetailsTemplate** еще один **DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding VerstatOperators}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVerstatOperator}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName}" Header="ПИБ" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMark}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" Header="Время, мин" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Его **ViewModel**

```
private IEnumerable<VerstatOperator> verstatOperators;
public IEnumerable<VerstatOperator> VerstatOperators
{
    get { return verstatOperators; }
    set
    {
        verstatOperators = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("VerstatOperators");
    }
}


private VerstatOperator selectedVerstatOperator;
public VerstatOperator SelectedVerstatOperator
{
    get { return selectedVerstatOperator; }
    set
    {
        selectedVerstatOperator = value;
        try
        {
            Marks = db.Marks.Where(x =>
                x.IdVerstatOperator == SelectedVerstatOperator.IdVerstatOperator).ToList();
        }
        catch { }
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedVerstatOperator");
    }
}


private List<Mark> marks;
public List<Mark> Marks
{
    get { return marks; }
    set
    {
        marks = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Marks");
    }
}


private Mark selectedMark;
public Mark SelectedMark
{
    get { return selectedMark; }
    set
    {
        selectedMark = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMark");
    }
}
```

Все работает кроме **SelectedMark**, выбирая любую строку из грида в деталях он просто не содержит объекта и всегда остаеться null.

Я так понимаю из-за вложенности этот грид имеет какое-то ограничение, как все-таки отлавливать выбранный элемент по **MVVM** канону

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMark"` это опечатка?

Comment: @FoggyFinder да

Comment: ...да неужели...и `Marks` тоже отображается как нужно? Установите нормально контекст и все будет работать.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper да Marks выводиться нормально под каждой записью. Куда уж еще нормальней установить контекст?

Comment: тогда дайте MCVE. Скопировал ваш код и - о чудо - marks не отобразились...поставил нормально контекст и все заработало.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper пример отображения [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xPe_RVB1C8p32cCKc4F6vg-WSCfKBLRw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Почему у вас `Marks` и `VerstatOperators` находятся на одном уровне? Когда вы ставите к верхнему `DataGrid` источник `VerstatOperators`, то он для вложенных элементов автоматом `DataContext` делает равным элемент `VerstatOperator`, поэтому у вас `ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}"` не работает - программа нечинает искать этот список в `VerstatOperator`. Вы должны `List<Mark> Marks` и `Mark SelectedMark` запихнуть в `VerstatOperator`. Или сделаете ещё один VM для `VerstatOperator`, где будут нужные списки.

Comment: Сразу поправлю себя. Судя по тому, что `ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}"` у вас работает, то рискну предположить, что `VerstatOperator` уже содержит одноимённый список. И вы ошибочно полагаете, что байндинг происходит к списку, что указан в вашем VM. Сразу второе: тот способ, что вы привели делает `SelectedMark` один для всех, вам разве это нужно? Или для каждого `VerstatOperator` вам нужен свой выбранный элемент?

Comment: @John вы все верно написали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким способом

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedMark, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```